# Mean of a sequence in $(0,1)$ converges if and only if Mean of the squared sequence converges.

Tags: real-analysis

If $(a_{n})$ is a sequence in $(0,1)$, show that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k} \rightarrow 0$ if and only if $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} a^{2}_{k} \rightarrow 0$.

It was easy to prove the $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k} \rightarrow 0 \implies \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} a^{2}_{k} \rightarrow 0$ part by basic comparison. I'm having trouble proving the opposite.

Comment: The Bryan/College Station - uh, Bunyanovski-Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Hint hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $(a_{n})$ is a sequence in $(0,1)$ such that $\\[8pt]$

$$
\frac
{a_1^2 + \cdots + a_n^2}
{n} 
\rightarrow \,0\;\;\text{as}\;\;n \rightarrow \infty
$$

The goal is to show

$$
\frac
{a_1 + \cdots + a_n}
{n} 
\rightarrow \,0\;\;\text{as}\;\;n \rightarrow \infty
$$

Following Sean Roberson's hint . . .$\\[8pt]$

\begin{align*}
0 \le \left(\frac{a_1 + \cdots + a_n}{n}\right)^2 &=
\left(
{\small{
\left\langle\frac{1}{n},\ldots,\frac{1}{n}\right\rangle
}}
\cdot
\left\langle{a_1,\ldots,a_n}\right\rangle
\right)^2
\\[4pt]
&\le
{
\left\lVert
{\small{
{\left\langle\frac{1}{n},\ldots,\frac{1}{n}\right\rangle}
}}
\right\rVert
}^2
\,
{
\left\lVert
{\phantom{\left\langle\frac{1}{n}\right\rangle}}
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
{\left\langle{a_1,\ldots,a_n}\right\rangle}
\right\rVert
}^2
\quad\text{[by Cauchy-Schwarz]}
\\[4pt]
&=
{\small{
\left(
{\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 + \cdots + \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2}
\right)
}}
\,
\left(
{a_1^2 + \cdots + a_n^2}
\right)
\\[4pt]
&=
\frac
{a_1^2 + \cdots + a_n^2}
{n}
\\[8pt]
\text{Then since}\;\;
&\frac
{a_1^2 + \cdots + a_n^2}
{n} 
\rightarrow \,0\;\;\text{as}\;\;n \rightarrow \infty
\\[4pt]
\text{it follows that}\;\;
&\left(
\frac
{a_1 + \cdots + a_n}
{n}
\right)^2
\rightarrow \,0\;\;\text{as}\;\;n \rightarrow \infty
\\[4pt]
\text{hence}\;\;&\frac
{a_1 + \cdots + a_n}
{n} 
\rightarrow \,0\;\;\text{as}\;\;n \rightarrow \infty
\\[8pt]
&\text{as was to be shown}\\[12pt]
\text{And here's }\text{an alternate proof}\;\text{. . .}
\qquad\qquad
&\\[12pt]
&0 \le 2a_ia_j \le a_i^2 + a_j^2,\;\text{for all$\;i,j\;$}\\[4pt]
\implies\; &0 
\le 
2\left(\sum_{1 \le i < j \le n} a_ia_j\right)
\le
(n-1)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\right)
\\[4pt]
\implies\; &0 
\le 
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 + 2\left(\sum_{1 \le i < j \le n} a_ia_j\right)
\le
(n)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\right)
\\[4pt]
\implies\; &0 
\le 
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^2
\le
(n)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\right)
\\[4pt]
\implies\; &0 
\le 
\left(
\frac
{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}
{n}
\right)^2
\le
\frac
{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2}
{n}
\\[8pt]
\text{Then as before, since}\;\;
&\frac
{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2}
{n}
\rightarrow \,0\;\;\text{as}\;\;n \rightarrow \infty
\\[4pt]
\text{it follows that}\;\;
&\left(
\frac
{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}
{n}
\right)^2
\rightarrow \,0\;\;\text{as}\;\;n \rightarrow \infty
\\[4pt]
\text{hence}\;\;&\frac
{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}
{n} 
\rightarrow \,0\;\;\text{as}\;\;n \rightarrow \infty
\\[8pt]
&\text{as was to be shown}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}